# How can I change the image size in a legend on pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, legend

[image]

I need the small picture as large as the word.But I didn't find how.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide any code (which you always should do on this site to make your problem clearer to others), so I don't know you concrete setup, But you can style the small image in the legend using the option `every legend image post`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        every legend image post/.append style={
            color=green,
            scale=2
        }
    ]

    \addplot coordinates {
        (0,4) (1,1) (2,2)
        (3,5) (4,6) (5,1)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Dataset}
        
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sry,I can't show my code, but really help, bro.

Comment: @xxy, you don't have to show your code, but *some code that reproduces the problem*. Not everybody has Jasper Habicht's awesome  crystal ball... 